Convert OData Filter to Expression on IQueryable
I have following class hierarchy:
public class Company
{
   public ICollection<CompanyType> CompanyTypes { get; set; } = new List<CompanyType>();
}

public class CompanyType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public static implicit operator int(CompanyType companyType) => companyType.Id;
}

This is my controller method:
public async Task<ActionResult<CompaniesResponse>> GetCompanies(ODataQueryOptions<GetCompaniesRequestV2> request) {  }

This is my goal:
Task<ActionResult<CompaniesResponse>> GetCompanies(ODataQueryOptions<GetCompaniesRequestV2> request)
{
var expression = // extracted expression from query
var query = new Query(request, expression);
var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
}

Now I would like to get a filter from OData query and convert it to an expression.
I am getting following error:

Could not find a property named 'Id' on type 'Edm.Int32'

This is my query:
$filter=CompanyTypes/any(s: s/Id eq 1)&$skip=0&$top=2

I tried to use this code:
//ODataQueryOptions<GetCompaniesRequestV2> request
...

IQueryable queryable = Enumerable.Empty<Company>().AsQueryable();
queryable = request.Filter.ApplyTo(queryable, new ODataQuerySettings());


Post your actual controller code. What you ask is done automatically by ASP.NET Core OData if your controller simply returns an IQueryable<T>. If you create a custom function that accepts ODataQueryOptions, you apply the settings to your query with optinos.ApplyTo(context.Companies), not the code you used. If you want to restrict what options can be applied you do with through ApplyTo's second parameter.

The reason this code doesn't work is because all the settings you configured when you registered OData are passed through the ODataQueryOptions.Context. The call you used though passes empty settings

Have you tried using OData as shown in the docs? All you need is a CompanyController:ODataController with the action public IQueryable<Company> Get()=>_context.Companies;. Nothing more. The OData condition that returns all companies with a specific Type ID should be ?$filter=CompanyType/Id eq '1'

The unusual conversion operator may be interfering as well. This code tells .NET to treat CompanyType as an integer (in certain situations) and the error complains it found an integer instead of the class.

@PanagiotisKanavos my controller accepts that:
{

}```

I can't do it as you described because I need to pass my request to another layer like here
```public async Task<ActionResult<CompaniesResponse>> GetCompanies(ODataQueryOptions<GetCompaniesRequestV2> request)
{
var expression = // extracted expression from query
var query = new Query(request, expression);
var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
}```

Edit the question and add the missing code there. I can't do what exactly? It's the extra code here that caused the problem. You can easily write request.AppliesTo(theRealContext,...). The code you posted simply won't work

And my goal here is to convert the Filter expression to C# Expression

I do not have access to context on controller level. I need something similar like described here but it does not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445062/how-to-transform-odata-filter-to-a-linq-expression

I strongly suggest going through the tutorials to see how ASP.NET Core OData really works in a normal scenario. I suspect a lot of extra libraries were added due to "best practices", making it simply impossible to use OData as designed

In any case that doesn't explain why you don't use query = request.AppliesTo(query,AllowedQueryOperations.Skip|AllowedQueryOperations.Top).
